# how to make voiceover read as per dom order section?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I have header and navigation and then next section with slider. since the slider section is having aria-live, screen readers read the slider contents directly. When i tab the menu navigation links, slider contents are read aloud and interuppted.

Answer (score 1):

VoiceOver already reads in DOM order.  If you have `aria-live` on an element and you update that element, you are telling VoiceOver to read the contents of that element.  That's the whole point of `aria-live`.

I'm guessing by "slider" you mean something like a carousel and **not** something like:

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50">
```

When a carousel rotates in new content, depending on how it's implemented, it might be updating the DOM and causing `aria-live` to be triggered.  However, most carousels already have all the elements and just hide/unhide them as the scroll into view.  Unhiding an element does **not** trigger an `aria-live` region.

If you have a carousel that rotates content in automatically, you will need a pause button to stop the carousel, otherwise you'd be violating [WCAG 2.2.2 Pause, Stop, Hide](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/time-limits-pause.html)